# Mongoose: Getting data from 2 collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I have 2 models `events` and `users`, i want to get number of users attended each event something like.

```
//expected result
[
    {
        "users": 50,
        "eventName": "Event one"
    },
    {
        "users": 46,
        "eventName": "Event two"
    },
    {
        "users": 63,
        "eventName": "Event three"
    }
]
```

The Schema are

```
//events
const eventSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        location: String,
        landmark: String,
        dateTime: String,
        status: {type:String, default: 1} //0-finished 1-live
    }
);

//users
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        image: String,
        email: {type: String, lowercase: true},
        password: String,
        events: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'events'}] //containes ids of events attended
    }
);
```

how do i query using mongoose or mongoDB, below is the method i'm trying somethig out

```
usersPerEvent: async (req, res, next) => {

    const events = await Event.find({});
    const users = await User.find({}).count();

    //expected result
    res.status(200).json({
        users: count,
        eventName: eventName
    });
},
```

Looking forward for much needed help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) followed by [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) & [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to count the no of users who attended event.

Something like

```
User.aggregate([
 {"$lookup":{
   "from":"events", // name of the collection
   "localField":"events",
   "foreignField":"_id",
   "as":"events"
 }},
 {"$unwind":"$events"},
 {"$group":{
     "_id":"$events.name",
     "users":{"$sum":1}
 }},
 {"$project":{
     "_id":0,
     "eventName":"$_id",
     "users":1
 }}
]).exec(function() {...})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, that worked perfectly.

Comment: just a query, if i change `_id` as eventName, i'm getting error as `The field 'eventName' must be an accumulator object`